# Simple RSpec redirect_to failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I have a controller that takes the `product.id` from the url slug and assigns it to the `@product` instance variable.

Product has a status, and if it isn't for_sale, visiting "/product/`product.id`" will redirect you to the `root_url`

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  before_action :still_available, only: [:new, :create]

def show
  @product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

  private

    def still_available
      product = Product.find_by(id: params[:id])
      unless product.for_sale?
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

app/spec/integration:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'product page', :type => :request do

  it 'redirects to the home page if product sold' do
    get "/product/2"
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)
  end
end
```

app/test/fixtures/products:

```
two:
  id: 2
  status: 2
```

(`status: 2` maps to `sold`)

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) product page redirects to the home page if product sold
     Failure/Error: get "/product/2"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `for_sale?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can you also post your product's `show` action.

Comment: I'm unable to test this so please test this on your own.  Try the syntax `get 'product', id: 2` instead of `get "product/2"`.  Your `product` is `nil` which leads to thinking `params[:id]` is blank or invalid.

Comment: @vee just tested, I get, `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):`

Comment: @vee neither... Could it not have to do with fixtures?

Comment: Have you checked your test database to confirm the fixtures have loaded?  You could do so using `rails db` on your terminal which should bring up db console.